# Directory tree data type?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, types, filesystems, directory-structure

What would be the return type of the following method? (`T`)

```
public T GetDirectoryContentsRecursively (string path) { ... }
```

The method will read the contents of a **remote** directory, and read the contents of each sub-directory and each of that object's sub-directories and so on.

I have thought about using `List<object>`, where `object` could be another `List<object>` etc... but I don't want the caller to have to be casting everything into `FileSystemInfo`s every time they want to use the method.

Every file must be a `FileInfo` and every directory a `DirectoryInfo`, both of which inherit the abstract class `FileSystemInfo`.

I just can't figure out what data type is best used to represent this.

Any ideas? Do I need to make my own `DirectoryTree` type?

**Edit:** The data is to be fetched from a server, probably directory by directory, one at a time. What I need to do is take this data and reconstruct it into *something* that I can pass to the user. This means I can't just pass a `DirectoryInfo`, then call its `GetFileSystemInfos()` because the Directory will not exist on the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe the approach is wrong, what are you trying to achieve with a tree structure that you can't by using the APIs directory as and when you need to?

If the intention is to just walk the folder/file structure on the remote directory then you don't necessary need to build your own in-memory representation to do this. If you are rendering the structure, just grab the top level, and load other levels on demand.

If you really want to go down this route then you could just return `IEnumerable<string>` with all the directory and file paths. `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` are relatively expensive objects. It all depends on purpose, can you give any more info?

Comment: I can't just return an `IEnumerable<string>` because I want to pass other information such as the size of each file, when it was modified etc... Perhaps you are right with your second paragraph and that I don't need this method at all. I already have a `public IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> GetDirectoryContents(string path)`.

Comment: I guess what I was thinking is once you have a list of file paths you can use the `File` and `Directory` APIs to lookup size and attribute info as and when you need them. Again it depends on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

see below information of SortedSet if you are uisng .net 4.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx

and Directory.Enumarate in .net 4.0 is desinged for the task you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

> class MySweetObject{
>     HashSet fileInfoSet;
>     HashSet directoryInfoSet;
>     //Logic needed to manipulate files as you see fit
>     //Logic needed to access files as you see fit
>   }

Then write it as:

> public MySweetObject GetDirectoryContentsRecursively (string path) { ... }

Create a custom object and pass that around to the caller.